# How to select only double matched records from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table like:

```
user ip
a 1.2.3.4
a 1.2.3.4
a 2.4.58.5
b 2.3.4.5
b 2.3.4.5
b 2.3.4.5
b 1.45.5.6 
c 12.4.2.4
c 12.4.2.4
c 1.2.3.4
d 12.4.2.4
d 12.4.2.4
e 1.45.45.45
e 1.45.45.45
f 1.55.55.55
```

As you see user a, c and d are having the same ip record.
How can I select such users out from a table?

I am using mysql.

Comment: please write your `output` that you want frpm this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT   ip, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user) AS users
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY ip
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT user) > 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f11/1/0).

Answer (score 2):

Although I like eggyal's answer, the question is "How can I select such users out from a table?".  So, I'll offer another answer that gives the users:

```
select distinct user
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.ip = t.ip and t2.user <> t.user);
```

And to elaborate, if you wanted the list of ip's for each user:

```
select user, count(*) as numIs, group_concat(ip) as IPs
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.ip = t.ip and t2.user <> t.user)
group by user;
```